# How do I show the html content in cn1 project?

Tags: codenameone

I want to view Html content in cn1 project, but the Html component and the webBrowser component of cn1 are all depreciated. The javadoc of BrowserComponent describes 'if you need wide compatibility and flexibility you should check out the HTMLComponent which provides a lightweight 100% cross platform web component'?

Is there any component for viewing Html content in cn1 component?

Answer (score 0):

Those comments are a bit old. `BrowserComponent` is available everywhere and should be used for web content rendering for anything non-trivial. Trivial UI should be assembled from Codename One components.